# Can I stack columns with Susy?

Tags: css, susy-sass

Loving Susy, so far! Now I'd like this initial layout...

[image: 3 Column Grid]

... to turn into this layout on a smaller screen:

[image: 2 Column Grid]

Is this possible using Susy? Furthermore, I'd want the AC-column to function as a single entity when they're in the same column, since I'd like to give them sticky behavior.

Comment: I'm guessing I just need to give column C a "clear:left"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to clear anything, you just need to space them differently. I've put together a simple [Sassmeister demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/4c8a495777cceed0ee09). Mine is set up mobile-first, with arbitrary total-columns and breakpoints, but you can change that however you want.

I wrapped `a` and `c` together in a single container, so you could treat them as a unit:

```
<div class="sticky">
  <div class="item a">A</div>
  <div class="item c">C</div>
</div>
<div class="item b">B</div>
```

At a small screen size, you lay out `sticky` to one side, and `b` to the other side, and then let `a` and `c` stack vertically inside `sticky`.

At a larger screen size, you want `sticky` to have no set `float`, `width`, `margin`, or anything else that gives it structure. You want it to collapse out of the way. Then you lay out `a`, `b`, and `c` next to each other — using `last` on `c` to set the correct order.

There would be other ways to pull this off with different source-orders, but hopefully this gives you a good start.